# WASM: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, system.text.json

I've added an option to my Blazor WASM app in order to register a specific configuration and use it inside my components with DI.

This is the inject step:

```cs
builder.Services.Configure<SDetails>(builder.Configuration);
```

These are the deserialization classes:

```cs
    public class SDetails
    {
        public List<StrategyDetails> StrategiesDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class StrategyDetails
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<string> Securities { get; set; }
        public List<Revision> Revisions { get; set; }
    }

    public class Revision
    {
        public string VersionTag { get; set; }
        public string Validity { get; set; }
        public List<string> Changes { get; set; }

        [JsonExtensionData]
        public JsonElement AppSettings { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the `appsettings.json`

```json
{
  "BaseAddress": "http://192.168.100.202:8081/api/",
  "StrategiesDetails": [
    {
      "Name": "_S005",
      "Description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "Securities": [
        "security 1",
        "Security 2"
      ],
      "Revisions": [
        {
          "VersionTag": "2.0.0",
          "Validity": "Dec 29, 2022 - Now",
          "Changes": [
            "Change 1",
            "Change 2"
          ],
          "AppSettings": {
            "StrategyNameId": "S12",
            "CloseTimeSafetyMargin": 2, 
            "OrderTimeLimit": 120, 
            "RetryCount": 3,
            "RetryInterval": 10, 
            "RunNow": false
          }
        },
        {
          "VersionTag": "1.0.0",
          "Validity": "Dec 29, 2021 - Dec 29, 2022 ",
          "Changes": [
            "Change 3",
            "Change 4"
          ],
          "AppSettings": {
            "StrategyNameId": "S34",
            "CloseTimeSafetyMargin": 2, 
            "OrderTimeLimit": 120, 
            "RetryCount": 3,
            "RetryInterval": 10, 
            "RunTomorrow": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Once I need to consume my `AppSettings` property an exception is generated:

```cs
[Inject]
public IOptions<SDetails> StrategiesDetails { get; set; } = default!;

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    _strategyDetails = StrategiesDetails.Value.StrategiesDetails.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == SelectedStrategy);
    var revision = _strategyDetails.Revisions.FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(revision.AppSettings);
}
```

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.CheckValidInstance()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonElement.WriteTo(Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.JsonElementConverter.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonElement value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Text.Json.JsonElement, System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51]].TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonElement& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[System.Text.Json.JsonElement, System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51]].WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonElement& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[JsonElement](Utf8JsonWriter writer, JsonElement& value, JsonTypeInfo`1 jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteString[JsonElement](JsonElement& value, JsonTypeInfo`1 jsonTypeInfo)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[JsonElement](JsonElement value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
```

`StrategiesDetails` is instantiated except for `AppSettings` property. How to solve it?

`AppSetting` could be avery time different in terms of properties/keys so I need to deserialize it dynamically. I've also already tried with a converter without solving it.

Answer (score 0):

The JsonElement "AppSettings" is part of the original JsonDocument representing the AppSettings file.

This line:

```
builder.Services.Configure<SDetails>(builder.Configuration);
```

will result in a JsonDocument being created from the source AppSettings file and then deserialized into your SDetails object.  Once deserialized, the JsonDocument is disposed.  As you've used JsonElement as the type for "AppSetting" (which is part of the source JsonDocument) it is also disposed after deserialization.

Try declaring AppSettings as

```
Dictionary<string, JsonElement> AppSettings
```

This should force the deserialization of the original JsonDocument to create a new Dictionary which will include NEW JsonElements that are not part of the original JsonDocument (I think).

If that doesn't work you could use:

```
Dictionary<string, object> AppSettings
```